# @ColumnTransformer is not working correctly for me

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

What I am trying is to **read data on a query**, and **write to a column** called endoso , which is a property, so that it can be persisted by the database, since this property is calculated and I want it to be displayed in the database.
But it is failing me when running my program. Anyone know what might be happening?

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "remesa_id", nullable = false)
@JsonBackReference
private Remesa remesa;
     
private Long endoso;

@ColumnTransformer(read = "(select count(*)"
+ " from Documento"
+ " inner join Remesa"
+ " on Remesa.id = Documento.remesa.id"
+ " inner join EnvioRemesa"
+ " on Remesa.id = EnvioRemesa.remesa.id"
+ " where Remesa.id=remesa.id)" //remesa.id is the id of the property remesa
, write = "endoso = ?" )
private Long writeEndosoInDataBase;
```

I do not know if I am using the ideal nomenclature to be able to what I comment

Comment: I see your querstion chain... Why don't you create a business class with a method "updateEndoso"? It makes a query and updates the record field.

Comment: I'm understanding you , but i don't know how to think about it actually